# JSON Date not passed correctly to the controller

Tags: jquery, datetime

I have an issue with the JSON date passing correctly from the View to the Controller and I need your help in this.

In the view, I have a date which is 29/11/2018. When I use the `date.toJSON()`, the value that I'm getting is `"2018-11-28T16:00:00.000Z"`. However, it is read as `28/11/2018 16:00` in the controller (the parameter that receives this is has a `DateTime` datatype.

I don't know what to do here and it really grinds my gears now.

This is how I do an ajax post:

```
var data = GetAllData();

$.ajax({
   url: myFile.api.SaveData,
   type: "POST",
   data: JSON.stringify(data),
   dataType: 'json',
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   success: function() {
      // Do something here
   }
});
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public object SaveData([FromBody] data)
{
   // DO SOMETHING HERE
}
```

Note: If this is a duplicate, then please redirect me to the link please.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, so that datetime is correct, what you expect it to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read from your question that the date is being parsed by .NET, but that you think it is the wrong date (28.11.2018 rather than 29.11.2018).

Your .NET DateTime type is per default unaware of timezones and doesn't alter anything. DateTime.Parse will accept the ISO 8601 string that Date.toJSON provides it.

The js Date() constructor, which you're probably using, creates a Date with the timezone set to that of the current system.

```
var d = new Date(2018, 11, 28)
d.toString()
"Fri Dec 28 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)"
d.toJSON()
"2018-12-27T23:00:00.000Z"
```

What you want is, guessing again, something like:

```
d = new Date(Date.UTC(2018, 11, 28))
d.toJSON()
"2018-12-28T00:00:00.000Z"
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> Note: Where Date is called as a constructor with more than one argument, the specified arguments represent local time. If UTC is desired, use new Date(Date.UTC(...)) with the same arguments.

also:
[javascript Date.UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC)

> The Date.UTC() method accepts the same parameters as the Date
>   constructor, but treats them as UTC